# Possible to enable historical Ligatures of Libertine font in Ubuntu system?

Tags: libertine, ligatures

I searched all of related posts but it seems that there is no solution in this case.

I really wann activate the feature of historical Ligatures of Libertine font e.g:

In Ubuntu system is it possible to do this by whatever compiler (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex,etc)?

Comment: See Libertine Ligatures at: http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=87&L=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

run it with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\Huge
st ct ff ffl fi ffi

\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+hlig}
st ct ff ffl fi ffi

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suppose that it is not possible with `pdflatex` and the Type 1 version of Libertine

Comment: it works like charm! Another question, how do I exclude only "st, ct" ligature?

Comment: there are three possible values `liga`, `dlig` & `hlig`. they can be enabled or disabled by +/-. And there is also a `fontspec` for setting the deafult TeX ligatures.

Comment: I found that the nummber '0' is like 'o' in text mode, and the arabic number in math mode looks quite different than in text mode. How do I figure this out? The font settings:  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc},  
\usepackage{libertine},
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

Comment: @KOF if you don't want oldstyle figures in the text you should call `libertine` with the `lining` option. [Check out the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/libertine).

Comment: @cgnieder  thank you so much. It does work. The only flaw with xelatex is that the Arabic numbers in math mode look like CM font. While with pdflatex, the numbers is identical to the libertine font.